# event.preventDefault() and event.StopPropagation is not allow us to override the functionality ctrl+p and ctrl+d and ctrl+t in mozilla

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

We are trying to override the functionality of shortcut buttons using javascript but few of those are not working as required in Firefox.
Like: I like to override Ctrl+P with my functionality using
event.preventDefault() and event.StopPropagation and same for Ctrl+t and Ctrl+d.But it is working fine in chrome.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent default events and stop bubbling events. They are supported by both browsers. It must be other part of the codes such as the one you are trying to override that is not wokring.

Comment: hi @RedPandaz 
Here is my code :
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == state.hotKeys.keyP) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            this.showOriginal()  //this is my seprate function which i am using for seprate functionality
        }